# Angular cannot access returned data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

In my Angular / Rails app, I am uploading a spreadsheet using the *angular-file-upload* gem. https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

I pass the spreadsheet to the Rails backend, and it processes the data and returns a JSON array.

The Angular code that passes the file up is this:

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {
  console.log('submit upload2');
  return $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
    url: '/api/batches/spreadsheet_upload.json',
    data: {
      id: 99,
      assembly: "xy"
    },
    file: $scope.file
  }).success(data, status, headers, config)(function () {
      debugger
    $scope.selector.tabledata = data;
    $scope.uploaded = true;
  });
};
```

Rails accepts the file and processes it. I am trying to return it with **render json: {data: spreadsheet_data}**

```
def spreadsheet_upload
  Rails.logger.debug("here params: #{params}")
  spreadsheet = nil
  case File.extname(params[:file].original_filename)
    when '.csv' then spreadsheet = Roo::CSV.new(params[:file].path)
    when '.xls' then spreadsheet = Roo::Excel.new(params[:file].path, nil, :ignore)
    when '.xlsx' then spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(params[:file].path, nil, :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end

  spreadsheet_header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  spreadsheet_data = []

  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[spreadsheet_header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    spreadsheet_data.push(row)
  end
  render json: {data: spreadsheet_data}
end
```

The network tab in Chrome shows me the data has been returned from the Rails server, but Angular doesn't seem to know what to do with it.

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.$scope.submitForm (http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/controllers/DesignViewCtrl.js?body=1:203:18)
    at http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/lib/angular.min.js?body=1:1936:30
    at http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/lib/angular.min.js?body=1:4127:15
    at Object.e.$eval (http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/lib/angular.min.js?body=1:2432:24)
    at Object.e.$apply (http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/lib/angular.min.js?body=1:2439:40)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/lib/angular.min.js?body=1:4126:15)
    at HTMLFormElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:2940:98)
    at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:2750:123)
```

Returned data in the network tab

```
{"data":[{"chrom":4.0,"chrom_start":55593607.0,"chrom_end":55593607.0},   {"chrom":"4","chrom_start":55593609.0,"chrom_end":55593617.0},{"chrom":"6","chrom_start":133105152.0,"chrom_end":133105152.0}]}
```

I have also tried changing to a response, but this also did not work.

```
  }).success(resp)(function () {
    $scope.selector.tabledata = resp.data;
    $scope.uploaded = true;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but the structure on the `success` that i have seen looks like

`.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.selector.tabledata = data;
    $scope.uploaded = true;
  });`